# JavaScript is preventing me to type in my textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox

i having this problem with my site. i can't click on any text input in my form except if i clicked the birthdate input first.
I had my tests and i found out that the problem is coming from the Root/prototype.js. it's not cleary mine that's why i don't know the problem. but it has a function which creates a wrapper and isolates the date input only. I don't know how to fix this without destroying the date picker.

the only solution i come up for now is to display a prompt that says "Please select your Birth Date first so we could confirm your age".

```
<script src="../Root/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="../Root/calendarview.js"></script>
<script>
  function setupCalendars() {
    // Embedded Calendar
    Calendar.setup(
      {
        dateField: 'embeddedDateField',
        parentElement: 'embeddedCalendar'
      }
    )

    // Popup Calendar
    Calendar.setup(
      {
        dateField: 'popupDateField',
        triggerElement: 'popupDateField'
      }
    )
  }

  Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { setupCalendars() })
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add a link to your site or create a js.fiddle for us to have a look at.

Comment: Please include the CSS you're using for the site (specifically for the input element and/or related).